# Conditional Decimal Place formatting

Tags: sql, sql-server, precision

I have a scenario where I need to display '-' if the value is null and Numeric data if not null. I have created a function which handles this. Below is the clip of the same.

```
 DECLARE @response varchar(max)  

 set @response=Case when (@data is null) then '-'  
      else STR(@data,25,@roundUp) 
     end  

      RETURN @response
```

I need response as below

```
@data=10258.69 and @roundUp=2 then @response=10258.69
@data=10258.00 and @roundUp=2 then @response=10258
@data=10258.695 and @roundUp=2 then @response=10258.70
@data=10258.69485 and @roundUp=2 then @response=10258.69
```

I tried below clause which works but don't in my query.

```
select cast(CAST(round(10028.000,3) as decimal(18,5)) as float)
```

Please suggest something that can solve this. Tried google.

Comment: I don't know what database you are using, but this is the sort of thing which is usually best handled in the presentation layer.  E.g. if you were using Java on top of a SQL database, you would have many handy functions to give the formatting you want here.

Comment: If could upvote @TimBiegeleisen comment 100 times I would. Don't store the exact format you need, store the number. When you pull it, format it then. Otherwise you will be forced to store a number as text and every time you deal with it you will have to cast it. It's expensive storage, and expensive retrieval.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, correct I should handle all this in Presentation Layer. but currently in a dead lock situation. Will definately change in my next update.

Comment: @AdityaPewekar You have an answer from Gordon below, hopefully this will help you.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes got one solution, the correct method is to handle in Presentation Layer as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the `case`:

```
set @response = (case when (@data is null) then '-'  
                      when (@data = floor(@data)) then str(@data, 25, 0)
                      else STR(@data,25,@roundUp) 
                 end);
return @response;
```

I would be careful about this, especially if `@data` is stored as a floating point number.  How do you want `11.001` to be represented?  `11.0000001`?

You might want:

```
set @response = (case when (@data is null) then '-'  
                      when abs(@data - floor(@data)) < 0.001 then str(@data, 25, 0)
                      else STR(@data,25,@roundUp) 
                 end);
return @response;
```

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. The first one worked for me.
If the data is 11.001 then the data sould be 11.001.

Answer (score 0):

You can use round and ceiling function like this. I leave upto you, How you want to incorporate it into your code:

```
Select round(Ceiling(10000*10258.69)/10000,2)
Select round(Ceiling(10000*10258.00)/10000,2)
Select round(Ceiling(10000*10258.695)/10000,2)
Select round(Ceiling(10000*10258.69485)/10000,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Late Answer, but If 2012+, another option is Format()

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol float)
Insert Into @YourTable values
 (10258.69)
,(10258.00)
,(10258.695)
,(10258.69485)
,(null)

Select *
      ,Formatted = IsNull(Format(SomeCol,choose(sign(SomeCol-floor(SomeCol))+1,'0','0.00')),'-')
 From  @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
SomeCol     Formatted
10258.69    10258.69
10258       10258
10258.695   10258.70
10258.69485 10258.69
NULL        -
```